# Turn off jQuery UI tooltip for certain elements

Tags: jquery-ui, tooltip

For simplicity, I'd like to enable the jQuery UI tooltip widget on all elements of the page:

Then disable it for certain elements or elements and their descendants.  But this doesn't seem to work:

```
$(document).tooltip({ track: true });
$('#menu *[title]').tooltip({ disabled: true });
```

My `$('#menu *[title]')` selector seems to work as I expect, getting all descendant elements that have a title attribute of the #menu element.

So why isn't the [disabled](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-disabled) option working in `.tooltip({ disabled: true });` to disable the tooltip on those elements? Is there another way and/or better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Set tooltip on all elements with:

```
$('*').tooltip();
```

And disable with

```
$('#menu *[title]').tooltip('disable');
```

A la:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uHuDp/1/)

Comment: You used $('input').tooltip() then used the code above and it worked.  That might be what I'll have to do with a broader selector, but I forked your jsfiddle and used $(document).tooltip() and the disable no longer works: http://jsfiddle.net/slolife/K6hRH/

Comment: @slolife: i don't think you can do `$(document).tooltip()`.  Try `$('*').tooltip()` instead: http://jsfiddle.net/K6hRH/1/

Comment: $('*') instead of $(document) is the ticket.  I only used $(document) because that is the example code on the jQuery UI demo site. Thanks. Add that to your answer and I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: Actually `$('#menu *[title]').tooltip('disable');` removes `title` attribute. But I just want to disable tooltip, its removing title attribute value so my jquery slider isn't working which is depending on that `title`.
Any other solution? except explicitly specifying tooltip for elements other than I don't want.

Answer (score 10):

None of the answers above worked for me, it seems like the way to do this now is to use the [items option](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-items):

```
$("*").tooltip({ items: ':not(.menu)' });
```

Comment: i would recommend '[title]:not(.menu)'

Comment: hey i have some problem here, i use jquery ui tooltips but my capcta show title WIDGET RECAPCTHA, then i use $('#recaptcha *[title]').tooltip('disable'); doesn't work

Comment: @FreddySidauruk I'm not sure why you're replying to this answer, your code doesn't seems to be based on it. You could try selecting using the items field, as per my answer,  $("*").tooltip({ items: '#recaptcha *[title]' }); assuming that is the right selector. Otherwise I don't think I can help you more, it's been a while since I last used jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

None of that worked for me and it has been driving me crazy.

This is what worked for me:

`$(document).tooltip({ content: function () { return $(this).not('#NoTipDiv *[title]').attr('title'); });`

$('*').tootip can heavily delay your page view!

Answer (score 3):

If you use selector instead of `$(document)`, don't forget to call that code at the right moment.

```
$(document).tooltip({show: false});
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#OK_Button').tooltip({disabled: true});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Update Nov 2022:
I tried suggestions from more answers and what worked for me was

```
$('#element_with_tooltip').tooltip({disabled: true})
```

The top answer with **tooltip('disable')** did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `$(':not(.menu *[title])').tooltip({ track: true });`?

Comment: As a replacement for both lines it changed nothing? Do you have a jsfiddle that demonstrates the issue? Edit: You have `.menu` in the first code block, but say that your `#menu` selector works as expected. Is that perhaps part of the problem?

Comment: I fixed the code in the question so that everything refers to #menu.  But your example still doesn't work with #menu.  I'll work on getting a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

According to jQueryUI docs as of my answer date.

`$( ".selector" ).tooltip( "option", "disabled", true );`

Comment: I see the docs here: https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-disabled  But this did not work for me to call `$(document).tooltip(options);` and then `$( ".mySelector" ).tooltip( "option", "disabled", true );`

Comment: Gives me `Uncaught TypeError: e[b] is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I am doing right now..

Show tool tip for:

- Exclude anything with class "noToolTip".
- And then include these:

  - A elements with TITLE attribute.
  - IMG elements with ALT attribute.
  - Anything with class "toolTip" and TITLE attribute.

Here is my javascript code.

```
// Set up tool tips for images and anchors.
$( document ).tooltip({
   items: "img[alt], a[title], .toolTip[title], :not(.noToolTip)",
   track: true,
   content: function() {
      var element = $( this );
      // noToolTip means NO TOOL TIP.
      if ( element.is( ".noToolTip" ) ) {
         return null;
      }
      // Anchor - use title.
      if ( element.is( "a[title]" ) ) {
         return element.attr( "title" );
      }
      // Image - use alt.
      if ( element.is( "img[alt]" ) ) {
         return element.attr( "alt" );
      }
      // Any element with toolTip class - use title.
      if ( element.is( ".toolTip[title]" ) ) {
         return element.attr( "title" );
      }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is struggling with this in ASP.NET MVC Razor pages. It is due to the razor helpers. You will need to add the following to the @Html.EditorFor attributes.

```
    autocomplete = "off"
```

Below is an example form group where you would do this.

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Field, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
   <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Field, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control date-field", autocomplete = "off" } })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Field, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

None of the above worked for me...but this did (after initializaion):

```
$("#selector").tooltip("disable");
```