# jQuery UI tooltips excluding select tags not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am using the jQuery UI tooltip widget and it seems to break on select tags in Internet Explorer. So I am excluding the select tags from the initialization. However, this doesn't seem to work because all the enhanced tooltips are now missing in Internet Explorer.

This is what I had before which didn't work with IE select tags:

```
<script>j(document).tooltip();</script>
```

Now I am switching to this code. The `j(document).not("select")` prevents the enhanced tooltips from showing. How do I make this code work?

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <script>j(document).not("select").tooltip();</script>  <-- Doesn't Work
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>
    <script>j(document).tooltip();</script>
<![endif]-->
```

I also tried this code from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144188/turn-off-jquery-ui-tooltip-for-certain-elements) but it still didn't work. None of the jQuery UI tooltips were displaying in any browser.

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <script>j('*').tooltip(); j('select').tooltip('disable');</script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>
    <script>j(document).tooltip();</script>
<![endif]-->
```

**Update:**

I tried this and am back to where I started:

```
<script>j('*').tooltip();</script>
<!--[if IE]>
<script>j('select').tooltip('disable');</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Are you missing the `DOM ready handler`

Comment: What browser will render `<!--[if !IE]>`???

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pdavis68/h26Vr/ Am I missing something? Seems to work fine in IE9

Comment: @BradM http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: @Pete No it doesn't work in IE9 or IE10. Did you try clicking on the select menu? It closes whenever you try to choose an item.

Comment: Do you have a valid `!DOCTYPE`?

Comment: @Daniel That was the thing I was missing.

Comment: @Cholesterol Yes `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: According to the ticket on this issue (http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8798), the solution is to wrap your select in a div (a span will work as well) and then put the title attribute on the div/span.

Comment: Oh, and for the record, I think that's a sucky resolution, but it is IE, so there may not have been a better one.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty ugly, but you can set your selector string in all browsers, override in IE, then actually call it.

```
<script>
    var tooltipSelector = "*";
</script>
<!--[if IE]>
<script> tooltipSelector = ":not(select)"</script>
<![endif]-->
<script>
    $(tooltipSelector).tooltip();
</script>
```

Side note: `$(document).not("select").tooltip()` selects the document, then removes all elements from the collection that are not `select` elements (which is all of them, since it's only a document), then tries to create tooltips on your (now empty) set.  It's an expensive no-op.

Answer (score 0):

Try conditional tags in a javascript solution:

```
var ie = (function(){

    var undef,
        v = 3,
        div = document.createElement('div'),
        all = div.getElementsByTagName('i');

    while (
        div.innerHTML = '<!--[if gt IE ' + (++v) + ']><i></i><![endif]-->',
        all[0]
    );

    return v > 4 ? v : undef;

}());

j(function(){

    if(!ie){

        //ie will be undefined if a different browser than IE is used
        //otherwise it will return the IE version
        //handle IE here

    }
    else {

        //handle the rest of the browsers here
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $("*").each(function(i, el){
        $(el).attr("mytitle", $(el).attr("title")).removeAttr("title");
    });

    $("*").tooltip({
        items: "[mytitle]:not([disabled])",
        content: function() {
            return $(this).attr("mytitle");
        }
    });
});
```