# JqueryUI Tooltip on modal button re-appears on modal close

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-tooltip

Hi there StackOverflowvians!

I'm learning to Javascript and JQuery and I've got a connundrum I'm not solving very well. I've used JqueryUI tooltips on some buttons. The tooltip uses the following code to display. I realize that my structure and organizational skills with regards to code suck, and there's probably a million more efficient ways to do what I'm doing, but bear with me - This is quite literally my first attempt at any kind of javascript.

```
$(function() {

    $("#button-menu").tooltip({
         position: {
         my: "top",
         at: "bottom+10",
         using: function( position, feedback ) {
             $( this ).css( position );
             $( "<div>" ).addClass( "arrow" ).addClass( "top" ).appendTo( this );
        }
    }
});

$("#button-menu").tooltip({ hide: { effect: "fadeOut", duration: 100 }, show: {   effect: "fadeIn", duration: 100 }});
});
```

So I'm calling a tooltip when you hover on the buttons, it's pretty and does what I want. A couple of the buttons when you click them lead to Modal Dialog windows. If one clicks a.search, one gets a modal dialog window with a search form. If one decides to simply close the modal window, it closes and whatnot. I note that when the modal is open, the tooltip closes and the state of the button returns to unfocused. When I close the Modal, the tooltip returns as if I'm hovering on the button - no matter where my mouse is positioned.

I tried to call blur on close for the button item for all buttons in the div, but to no avail. I might try setting a timeout on that function next, because somewhere the tooltip function is re-instating the aria-tooltip class after the button close event and I suppose if I can wait it out I can close it after it opens, but that feels sloppy. The code below was my interpretation of the correct way to call a dialog and close the tooltip for the button on dialog close, but it doesn't do what I think it should. The tooltip still re-appears

```
 $(function() {
 $( "#searchform" ).dialog({
  modal: true,
  autoOpen: false,
  close: function( event, ui ) {$('a.search').blur();},
  show: {
    effect: "fade",
    duration: 500
  },
  hide: {
    effect: "fade",
    duration: 1000
  }
 });

 $( "a.search" ).click(function() {

 $( "#searchform" ).dialog( "open" );

 });
 });
```

edit: I suppose I should ask the question - why is this behavior happening, and is there something I can do identify how that tooltip is firing, or just stop it from reappearing when I close the modal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dialog widget has an [open() event](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open). I'd be inclined to us it to disable tooltips ([like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144188/turn-off-jquery-ui-tooltip-for-certain-elements)), and re-enable them on [close()](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close) by naming your init function and calling it.

Something like:

```
$('.dialogSelector').dialog({
  open: function( event, ui ) {
    $('.tooltipSelector').tooltip('disable');
  }
});

$('.dialogSelector').dialog({
  close: function( event, ui ) {
    $('.tooltipSelector').tooltip();
    // OR
    myTooltipFunction();
  }
});
```

Comment: This ended up being back door helpful - when I tried it out and it didn't work as expected I figured out that my animation length on dialog close was causing issues with the timing of the dialog close: functions. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. What solved it for me was adding an 'Ok' buton

```
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 200,
        width: 440,
        modal: false,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
         }
    });
```