# Disable jQuery UI Tooltips except for certain elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tooltip

I'm looking for the inverse of what's being done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144188/turn-off-jquery-ui-tooltip-for-certain-elements). I would like to disable the tooltips except in certain situations.

Here's the code I'm using now, just not sure what/where to add a disable:

```
$(function() {
$( document ).tooltip({
  position: {
    my: "center bottom-20",
    at: "center top",
    using: function( position, feedback ) {
      $( this ).css( position );
      $( "<div>" )
        .addClass( "arrow" )
        .addClass( feedback.vertical )
        .addClass( feedback.horizontal )
        .appendTo( this );
    }
  }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a specific selector instead of `document`

```
$(function () {
    $("a.has-tooltip, p").tooltip({
        position: {
            my: "center bottom-20",
            at: "center top",
            using: function (position, feedback) {
                $(this).css(position);
                $("<div>")
                    .addClass("arrow")
                    .addClass(feedback.vertical)
                    .addClass(feedback.horizontal)
                    .appendTo(this);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jp32fqd/)